# Observable emits in sequence and gets inputs from the previous one

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have 2 observables and the 2nd one takes the return of the 1st one as its argument. The code looks like the following but how can `o2$` take the return of `o1$`?

```
let o1$ = this.apiService.get1();
let o2$ = this.apiService.get2();

o1$.pipe(
    map(data => data['id']),
    concat(o2$)
).subscribe(x => log('completed'));
```

Comment: It depends on how `o2$` want to use the result from `o1$`

Comment: @martin The 2nd observable needs the result from the 1st one as its argument. Basically the 1st one returns me an ID and the 2nd one grabs that ID to find me the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `flatMap` here, like so:

```
let o1$ = this.apiService.get1();

o1$.pipe(
    flatMap(data => this.apiService.get2(data['id'])),
).subscribe(x => log('completed'));
```

Comment: Should I use `concatMap` rather than `flatMap`? This is because `o1$` has to finish first and then `o2$` start.

Comment: You can do, yes. If they're HTTP calls, it won't make a difference